# Android string extraction

Tags: java, android

I have an abstract class which contains method for setting header text. It looks like:

```
TextView header = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hTitle);
header.setText(getString(this.getHeaderStringID()));
```

At this moment methods that override the abstract getHeaderStringID() return integers like 0x7f040001.
1 I wonder whether there's a way to utilize concatenation or somewhat similar to achieve this:

```
header.setText(getString(R.string.!getHeaderStringID!));
```

In desired case getHeaderStringID would return string like "sAboutHeader"

2 I'm new to Java - can I get rid of creating header object. If I don't do like that, eclipse validator says that the appropriate method isn't found and doesn't let me launch app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think that you should use reflection:

```
try {
        Field idField = R.String.class.getDeclaredField(getHeaderStringID());
        int value = idField.getInt(idField);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
```

the value variable could be given as an input to the getString() function.

Comment: it works like that now, but it returns integer. What I want to do is to set to each subclass it's own **string** identifier in order to achieve header.setText(getString(R.string. here comes some magic that appends my string identifier to R.string.  ));

Comment: After you'd manage to apend the unique string to R.string, it would return you an integer as well.